# Django Admin Foreign Key Error on Djongo database engine

Tags: django, mongodb, orm, djongo

I'm using [djongo](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo) package for a database backend engine in order to connect to MongoDB and define my models on it.

settings.py:

```py
DATABASES = {
  # 'default': {
  #   'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
  #   'NAME': str(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'),
  # },

  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'djongo',
    'NAME': 'djongo-db',
    'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': False,
    'CLIENT': {
      'host': 'localhost',
      'port': 27017,
      'username': 'root',
      'password': 'root',
      'authSource': 'admin',
      'authMechanism': 'SCRAM-SHA-1'
    }
  }
}
```

models.py:

```py
class EventModel(BaseModel)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class CalendarModel(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    event = models.ForeignKey(to=EventModel, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

and admin.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import CalendarModel, EventModel


@admin.register(CalendarModel)
class CalendarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['_id']

@admin.register(EventModel)
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['_id']
```

It works fine with using SQLite backend and it's working when djongo backend without foreign key field but gives me an error when using the **djongo backend** and has foreign key field. It said:

[image: error image]

As you can see in the image above, it can load objects from the database and detects the relation correctly, but it can't save it.

And I can't create a new object with relation to another object.
How I can fix this?

Update

---

I can create objects using code like this, the problem seems to be from Django admin site

```py
e = EventModel.objects.first()
CalendarModel.objects.create(name="test", color="red", event=e)
```

Comment: Put `blank=True` in event field..

Comment: @Pradip I do that but that error exist yet :(

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that when you try to save an instance of an object with **PK an ObjectId** that it is transformed into a **string** and consequently no longer corresponds to an instance of an object, so with the override of the **get_form** method in **POST** you can intercept this data and change the **string to ObjectId**, but as you can see in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects):

> The **QueryDicts** at **request.POST** and **request.GET** will be immutable when
> accessed in a normal request/response cycle.

so you can use the recommendation from the same documentation:

> To get a mutable version you need to use **QueryDict.copy()**

or ... use a little trick, for example, if you need to **keep a reference** to an object for some reason or leave the object the same:

```
# remember old state
_mutable = data._mutable

# set to mutable
data._mutable = True

# сhange the values you want
data['param_name'] = 'new value'

# set mutable flag back
data._mutable = _mutable
```

where data it is your **QueryDicts**

In this case:

```
@admin.register(CalendarModel)
class CalendarModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('....')
    ....

    def get_form(self, request, obj, change, **kwargs):
        if request.POST:
            # remember old state
            _mutable = request.POST._mutable
            # set to mutable
            request.POST._mutable = True
            # сhange the values you want
            request.POST['event'] = ObjectId(request.POST['event'])
            # set mutable flag back
            request.POST._mutable = _mutable

        return super().get_form(request, obj=obj, change=change, **kwargs)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Post edited with explanation